# mouseover not working for dynamic generated li in ie7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, ie7.js

I have created a menuItems array and assigned it to a div which has an id of “leftMenu”.

I have a dynamically generated the UL (user list) and LI and it's append to the div.

I have set two attributes “onmouseover”, and “onmouseout” in the dynamically generated LI.

These two attribute do not work in IE7 but IE8, IE9, Firefox, Safari and Chrome it works fine.

**CSS:**

```
    ul{margin:0px; padding:0px; width:200px;}
    li{list-style-type:none;}

    .defaultsMenuBtn {
    background-color: #FEE6A0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    color: #002C84;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    }

    a{text-decoration:none;}

    .defaultsMenuBtn_hover{background-color: #FFD14F; padding: 3px 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;font-weight:bold; color: #002C84; cursor:pointer;}
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="leftMenu">  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var menuItems=new Array();
    menuItems[0]="menu01";
    menuItems[1]="menu02";
    menuItems[2]="menu03";
    menuItems[3]="menu04"; 

    var menulength = menuItems.length;
    var MenuWapper = document.getElementById("leftMenu");
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");

    MenuWapper.appendChild(ul);

    for(i=0; i<menulength; i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var itemID = "item_"+i
    li.className = "defaultsMenuBtn";
    li.id = itemID
    var browser = navigator.appName;

    li.setAttribute("onmouseover","this.className='defaultsMenuBtn_hover'");
    li.setAttribute("onmouseout", "this.className='defaultsMenuBtn'");
    li.innerHTML = " "+menuItems[i]+"";
    ul.appendChild(li);

    }// end forloop
```

Please let me know if any more information is required!

Answer (score 0):

I’m not 100% sure why it doesn’t work in IE7, but I don’t think `.setAttribute('event','fn')` is supported in IE7-. You should probably replace:

```
li.setAttribute("onmouseover","this.className='defaultsMenuBtn_hover'");
li.setAttribute("onmouseout", "this.className='defaultsMenuBtn'");
```

With

```
li.onmouseover = function() {
    li.className='defaultsMenuBtn_hover';
}

li.onmouseout = function() {
    li.className='defaultsMenuBtn';
}
```

Setting inline attributes is not a good way to add listeners anyway, it’s better done in javascript.

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is because IE7 only has partial support of setAttribute, it doesn't support adding event handlers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536739(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks @Duopixel I knew I had read something like that 6 years ago :)

Comment: Thanks David  

Here have made litter change in code

    li.className='defaultsMenuBtn_hover';
    li.className='defaultsMenuBtn

to

    this.className='defaultsMenuBtn_hover';
    this.className='defaultsMenuBtn

Now it’s working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in IE7 DOM has restrictions for dynamically added elements.

You have to use the `live()` or `delegate()` method with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David

Here I have made litter change in code

```
li.className='defaultsMenuBtn_hover';
li.className='defaultsMenuBtn
```

to

```
this.className='defaultsMenuBtn_hover';
this.className='defaultsMenuBtn
```

Now it’s working fine.